# Guest system managed by libvirt doesn't start after successful installation

Tags: kvm-virtualization, lvm, libvirt

- Host system — Ubuntu 12.04.
- Virtualization — KVM.
- Disks — LVM.

Guest system installation was successful.
But after restart:

```
Booting from Hard Disk...
Boot failed: could not read the boot disk

Booting from Floppy...
Boot failed: could not read the boot disk

No bootable device.
```

Load system with SystemRescueCD — all disks found and readable.

*/etc/libvirt/qemu/chef0.xml:*

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>chef0</name>
  <uuid>f1dcd38a-f9cb-f384-f0f2-3037e1b957f7</uuid>
  <memory>786432</memory>
  <currentMemory>786432</currentMemory>
  <vcpu>1</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-1.0'>hvm</type>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source dev='/dev/virvg/chef0-root'/>
      <target dev='sda' bus='scsi'/>
      <boot order='1'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source dev='/dev/virvg/chef0-swap'/>
      <target dev='sdb' bus='scsi'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='scsi' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:f3:07:98'/>
      <source network='default'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5900' autoport='no' listen='127.0.0.1'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
    </graphics>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Please help solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by changing `<target dev='sda' bus='scsi'/>` to `<target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>`

Comment: why would you have to change this